# ajax does not get data from the controller in laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-4

I want to perform multiple operation when i select value from dropdownbox for that i am using ajax in larvel.My problem is when i select dropdown list value it get passsed through the ajax,from ajax it calls controller based on that i want fetch required filed from datatabase but ajax does not return any success result.Here is my code.

**view**

```
 {{ Form::select('asset_type_id', $assettype_list,
Input::old('asset_type_id',  $assetdetail->asset_type_id), array('class'=>'select2','id'=>'asset_type_id', 'style'=>'width:350px')) }}
```

**ajax**

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#asset_type_id").change(function() {debugger;
        // alert($('#asset_type_id option:selected').val());
        var data=$('#asset_type_id option:selected').val()
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Controllers/Admin/AssetdetailsController',
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data)
            {
                check(data);
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
                alert('Something went to wrong.Please Try again later...');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**controller**

```
public function postPositions($data) 

    {
        if (Request::ajax()) 
        {
            $positions = DB::table('asset_types')->select('is_nesd')->where('id', '=', $data)->get();

            return  $positions;
                 }
    }
```

**route**

```
 Route::post('Controllers/Admin', [usesu'Controllers\Admin\AssetdetailsController@postPositions');
```

Answer (score 1):

In your **ajax**, try to change the URL:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#asset_type_id").change(function() {debugger;
        // alert($('#asset_type_id option:selected').val());
        var data=$('#asset_type_id option:selected').val()
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '{{ URL::route('post_form') }}',
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data)
            {
                check(data);
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
                alert('Something went to wrong.Please Try again later...');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And in your **route** (see [Laravel 4 Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#named-routes))

```
 Route::post('Controllers/Admin', array('uses' => 'Controllers\Admin\AssetdetailsController@postPositions', 'as'=>'post_form'));
```

**Update**

To solve the error with the **controller**, try this:

```
public function postPositions()
{
    if (Request::ajax())
    {
        $data = Input::get('form_data');
        $positions = DB::table('asset_types')->select('is_nesd')->where('id', '=', $data)->get();

        return  $positions;
    }
}
```

And the JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#asset_type_id").change(function() {debugger;
        // alert($('#asset_type_id option:selected').val());
        var f_data=$('#asset_type_id option:selected').val(); // changed

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '{{ URL::route('post_form') }}',
            data: { form_data: f_data }, // changed
            cache: false,
            success: function(data)
            {
                check(data);
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
                alert('Something went to wrong.Please Try again later...');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I changed both route and url, same problem remains exist.

Comment: If run this i got exception                                         Missing argument 1 for Controllers\Admin\AssetdetailsController::postPositions()C:\inetpub\wwwroot\snipe-it\app\controllers\admin\AssetdetailsController.php#140ErrorException

     
     
     
     public function postPositions($id) 
     {
            if (Request::ajax()) 
      {

Comment: Thank you for your reply,i solved the above problem but now  i am facing the new problem i posted the updated code in new link. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26562696/controller-not-get-id-from-the-route-in-laravel/26562867#26562867]

Answer (score 0):

you may need to change URL to  url: '/Controllers/Admin'.

Because you made Route as  Controllers/Admin.

Comment: I posted the full code above,i think the problem is in routing.In javascript we check using debugger,likewise i want to check whether the data is passing in controller or not can you help me..

Answer (score 0):

View:

```
            {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'crud', 'method' => 'get', 'id' => 'myform', 'name' => 'myform')) }}
                     {{ Form::select('application',$download_options, Input::get('application'),$options = array('id' => 'application', 'class' => 'application'))  }}
                        {{ Form::label('date', 'date', array('id' => 'date_label')); }}
                        {{ Form::select('date', $options = array('id' => 'date', 'class' => 'date')) }}
                        {{ Form::submit('Display', array('class' => 'btn btn-small btn-info', 'id' => 'submit')) }}
            {{ Form::close() }}




          <script>

            $(document).ready(function($) { 
            $('#application').change(function(e){ // e=event
            var application = $('#application option:selected').val();
            $.getJSON('/getdata/'+application, function(data){
            $('select#date').html('$'+data);

            });

    });
        });

    </script>
```

Route:

```
                 Route::get('getdata/{application}', function($application){
                $selectboxtwo =  DB::table('downloads')
               ->where('application', '=',$application)
                ->groupBy('date')
                ->lists('date');
                 return $selectboxtwo;
```

Comment: A little explanation of what you've done would be really helpful. And please format your code properly.